# Widget shortcode Name attribute

Tags: layout, blocks, widgets

If I insert a widget in content in CMS, is it possible to define the name of the widget? Like

```
{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" name="NAME_HERE" display_type="all_products" products_count="2" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}
```

So I can use it later in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible.
The blocks or widgets you define using `{{...}}` directives are instantiated and processed on the fly and the `{{}}` directive is replaced by the real HTML as the page is being constructed. They are not added to the layout object.